# Python3 PyCrypto - ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I am experimenting with the `PyCrypto` library. My friend gave me the public key (base64) they used to encrypt a string, the ciphertext, and the IV. The cipher they used was `AES-CBC`. I thought this would be relatively straightforward, but I am getting the error `ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long`. Below are my code, traceback, and findings:

`CODE:`

```
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

message = "GgFyMNGjCOnrE3NjNEYko57ZUdy36ldB+/WrR5+ctN6jglicmb3ONvY4mfswk09BUmm0rCBy6yyaTFWKWuEgnMtu0RpbyyHICCQAVTmgwtgQ9wWlE1BJJAHJsZd61cMlsLomtRtCuNOnX5fnoGcs2X=="

key = b'xSAU2gWfDhWusUPplf8RtWknJ0ZKZ+dqK23/go8i0ls='
print(sys.getsizeof(key))

iv = b'WmiBaaAuyX7YCSTTPj07/c=='
print(sys.getsizeof(iv))

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decd = aes.decrypt(message)
print(decd)
```

`TRACE:`

```
77
65
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 95, in new
    return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 59, in __init__
    blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long
```

As you can see, the key size is 77 bytes, and the IV size is 65 bytes. I am simply using the key and the IV that was provided to me that encrypted the original text (I am aware of the security implications of putting keys in plain-text. These are not the actual keys, just random strings of the same length for demonstration purposes).

Comment: Ciphertext, key and IV seem to be Base64 encoded. They must be Base64 decoded, see [`base64.b64decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode). [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) is not very useful here, [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) is more applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode both the `key` and `iv` but also you have to decode the `message` otherwise it wont be 16 bytes aligned as you are using `CBC` mode.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

message = b"GgFyMNGjCOnrE3NjNEYko57ZUdy36ldB+/WrR5+ctN6jglicmb3ONvY4mfswk09BUmm0rCBy6yyaTFWKWuEgnMtu0RpbyyHICCQAVTmgwtgQ9wWlE1BJJAHJsZd61cMlsLomtRtCuNOnX5fnoGcs2X=="
message = base64.b64decode(message)

key = b'xSAU2gWfDhWusUPplf8RtWknJ0ZKZ+dqK23/go8i0ls='
key = base64.b64decode(key)

iv = b'WmiBaaAuyX7YCSTTPj07/c=='
iv = base64.b64decode(iv)

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decd = aes.decrypt(message)
print(decd)
```

Comment: This might be out of scope for this question, but when i use the `decrypt()` method, it returns a byte object that I am assuming is `utf-8` encoded. However, when I use the `decode()` method, i.e. `decd = decd.decode()`, I get this error, `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 0: invalid start byte`.

Comment: @CynicalFly try decoding ```latin1``` but I already tried and the plaintext seems to make no sense are you sure it's just readable text you said "assuming"?.

Comment: I made a separate question to track this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985194/python3-pycrypto-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8e-in-p